# How can I add the values in the dataset together in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to add values together for each year in my dataset.

The dataframe looks like..

[image]

I'd like to add the values in `NUMBER OF MOSQUITOES` column, collect them in the year to which it belongs.

For example,

```
2007 395
2008 154
2009 353
...
...
...
```

Which methods in `pandas` or `numpy` can I use?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: pretty sure there's a "sumby" or similar that will help

Comment: Thank you a lot! I can think of it now because of your answer. I just use `df.groupby('SEASON YEAR').sum()`. Am I correct?

Comment: `df.groupby('year').number_of_mosquitoes.sum()`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to sum the number of mosquitoes in every year.
If that's the case, you can use groupby.sum(), like this:

```
df.groupby(['SEASON YEAR'], as_index=False).sum()
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, tell me otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. This would be another way to sum them. Very appreciated by your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `groupby` and `sum`:

```
df.groupby("SEASON YEAR").sum()["NUMBER OF MOSQUITOES"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great!